# How to change baseurl in magento

Tags: mysql, magento-1.9.1, base-url

I need your suggestion for changing the baseurl in magento, using admin i have successfully changed. But i want to know how to change the baseurl directly in database table.

Comment: I changed the baseurl using admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by changing values of `'web/(secure or unsecure)/base_url'` in `'core_config_data'` table of your database.

Comment: i have checked the values in core_config_data but cant find anything

Comment: Check again that's not possible. There are two rows 1] web/secure/base_url 2] web/unsecure/base_url. See here--> https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-change-magento-base-urls.html

Comment: Thanks @Vishwas Soni. I dont know why i couldnt locate the two rows. i used the select query `SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE path="web/unsecure/base_url";`. It returns zero results. I also checked the table row by row but cant found anything.

Comment: Welcome. It should be there. Otherwise your magento shouldn't work. Please mark correct as answer if it helps you. So whenever some one came through the answer they will see as a correct answer. It will help them.

Comment: Thanks @Vishwas. I found it